# Reading postData sent using dojox.fileUploader

Tags: servlets, post

I am using dojox.form.FileUploader to upload a file. I am sending "username" alongwith the files, hence I use:

```
var fileUploader = new dojox.form.FileUploader({
           uploadUrl: "upload.jsp",
            postData:{
             userId:"[abc@gmail.com]"
           }
       });
```

Now I am trying to read the post data in FileUploader.java file, 
I extract the file item and the field name as : item.getFieldName()); which gives "postData". However, how to read the value abc@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `item.getString()`